# Terminal icon in window titlebar is stretched out over window control buttons

Tags: icons, themes, gnome-terminal, titlebar, window-buttons

A while ago I upgraded from Ubuntu 17.04 to Ubuntu 17.10 and everything is working fine except for the fact that the icon in the window title bar of my Terminal seems to be stretched out to some ridiculous size.

[image]

This only seems to happen in the Terminal window. The Nautilus icon is completely fine.

[image]

The problem seems to go away if I login into an Xorg session instead of a Wayland one. I've looked around and didn't find any immediate solution to this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 13):

this is due to missing icons with proper resolution, try installing `gnome-icon-theme` then ensure the icons are selected with `gnome-tweak-tool`:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-icon-theme gnome-icon-theme-extras
```

you can also keep your existing icons, the `gnome-icon-theme` will simply replace the buggy icon on the terminal window (after restart)

Answer (score 2):

As Ahmad Nassri points out this is an icon problem. Specifically please read this [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-themes/+bug/1718238) carefully to confirm you are having the same problem.

If so review all the comments. Of particular interest is comment #8:

```
sudo apt install gnome-icon-theme # fixes
sudo apt purge gnome-icon-theme # breaks
```

You can keep following this **8 month old** bug report by subscribing to email to find out when a permanent fix is in.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with Ubuntu 18.04 and Papirus icon theme and I solved it by changing icon theme in GNOME Tweak Tool to `Papirus-Adapta-Nokto` and then back to `Papirus-Adapta`.

I know this workaround might be specific for my case, but I believe it's worth trying when you have similar problem.