# How do I remove icon from title bar of Terminal window?

Tags: 18.04, icons, gnome-terminal, window, titlebar

How would I go about removing this icon from the title bar of my Terminal window?

[image: this picture]

It really messes up themes when I use them.

Comment: the solution in a similar thread should work https://askubuntu.com/a/1010473/896714

Answer (score 3):

To *remove* the icon, either

- Turn *on* the Application menu in Gnome Tweak. This shows the application menu in the Gnome topbar (icon + name) instead of in the application window (icon only).
- Edit the key `org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout 'appmenu:close'` to remove `appmenu:`. This way, an appmenu icon will never be shown, even if you turn the application menu in the Gnome topbar off.

If instead, in response to the comments, you would decide to *keep* the icon and restore its appearance to normal, then try the solutions that was mentioned in the comments:  [Terminal icon in window titlebar is stretched out over window control buttons](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974687/terminal-icon-in-window-titlebar-is-stretched-out-over-window-control-buttons)