# Ubuntu 18.04 Terminal Showing unwanted stuff!

Tags: command-line, 18.04

Was trying to drag a package in the terminal and now I see a strange command line icon besides minimize and close icons. It looks like this:

[Terminal Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPIhR.jpg)

It's very annoying... Is there any way to repair terminal or fix this without loosing data or Ubuntu.

Comment: Does this help: [How do I remove icon from title bar of Terminal window?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1095837/how-do-i-remove-icon-from-title-bar-of-terminal-window)

Comment: Yes... It helped. Thanks! It was Application icon which was showing at the corner.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried reinstalling the gnome terminal with:

```
sudo apt purge gnome-terminal && sudo apt install gnome-terminal
```

Comment: Not yet, I haven't tried that!

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work!