# Weird Image on the top right of terminal!

Tags: 18.04

There is a constant image on the top of the minimize icon of the terminal.
I earlier changed the icon pack, but then chose one of the defaults provided. Changing the theme of Ubuntu also doesn't remove this image.

I tried restarting the OS, still no help.
Ubuntu 18.04 (bionic)
Gnome 3.28.2
Kernel 5.0.0-27-generic
(Its just annoying, otherwise no functionality is affected)

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://askubuntu.com/questions/974687/terminal-icon-in-window-titlebar-is-stretched-out-over-window-control-buttons

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Terminal icon in window titlebar is stretched out over window control buttons](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974687/terminal-icon-in-window-titlebar-is-stretched-out-over-window-control-buttons)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seemed like an icon error.

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-icon-theme
```

and then selecting , 'gnome' under tweaks, solved this issue.

\m/