# Display problem with terminal icon

Tags: 18.04, gnome-terminal

I have a problem with terminal icon display, I don't know what I have to do, the problematic icon is on the top right of the picture:

[image: terminal.png]

Comment: This is a know issue with themes on Ubuntu 18.04. Possible duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/974687/terminal-icon-in-window-titlebar-is-stretched-out-over-window-control-buttons/1010473

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try reinstalling gnome-shell
and gnome

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install gnome`

`sudo apt-get install gnome-shell`

hope it may help

Comment: Thank you ! It works perfectly !