# Getting a small arrow on top bar's right corner. Only for terminal. How to remove it?

Tags: icons, themes, gnome-terminal, titlebar, window-buttons

The arrow doesn't effect the function of the buttons as I’m still able to use all the 3 keys. I guess it's just an overlay:

[image: arrow]

Comment: Change your theme to a default theme: it will be removed.

Comment: That's not actually an arrow, it's the icon of the Terminal application itself. Does this answer your question? [Terminal icon in window titlebar is stretched out over window control buttons](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974687/terminal-icon-in-window-titlebar-is-stretched-out-over-window-control-buttons)